# android studio showing error sign

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: error image]

I am using android studio 1.4 . This is showing error sign whenever I adding drawable as background of my LinearLayout but is not showing details about this error. Any suggestion please. 
my popup_shape.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:startColor="#DD000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: when you execute your code does it work or is the background drawable missing?

Comment: I noticed that too and I decide to ignore it

Comment: vivekh @this is working fine. But I need to confirm that it is not my fault.

Comment: Blackbelt@ thanks for responding. ok then I should decide to ignore this also.

Comment: Same here. It shows the error symbol for any `background=@drawable` ...and I'm also just ignoring it.